# Android Studio: Can not calculate Diff

Tags: android-studio, ide

My compare files utility from Android Studio 2.3.3 is not working anymore, it shows the message *"Can not calculate diff"* and generate the following error on Event Log:

```
NullPointerException: update failed for ActionGroup: null (null)[null]
```

[Here is the log captured by the Report to Google dialog](https://pastebin.com/erkjT0Mk)

I'm using Mac, I already uninstalled Android Studio, Android-sdk, cloned the project again from git and deleted the Android folder under *~/User/MyUser/Library/Android*, but the problem continues. 
It does not happen with the other computers from my team.

Anyone knows how to fix this? It wasn't happening last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete Android Studio.app
2. Delete the following folders:

   - ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio
   - ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio
   - ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio
   - ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio
3. Reinstall Android Studio.